# Wrong Assembly Version Loaded

Tags: c#, assemblies

I am working on a plugin which requires some extra assemblies. One of these assemblies already exists in the root application folder. This version is wrong and I manually upload the correct version to a separate folder.

Problem is, as [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf.aspx) mentions, by the time I get to loading my version of the assembly, it looks like the application already auto-loads the root folder one, even though it is the wrong number (?). Since the name is already in memory it ignores my assembly.

I've seen many similar questions, but no magic bullet answer. This problem seems like it might come up a lot in plugin-type architectures, any ideas?

EDIT:

I used FusionLog to get the full info: here's how the whole thing happens:

```
LOG: Appbase = file:///D:/test/

LOG: Initial PrivatePath = D:\test\Sandbox

LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/test/mydll.DLL.

LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: D:\test\mydll.dll

LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase.

LOG: Assembly Name is: mydll, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a446968a32b751de

WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Minor Version

ERR: The assembly reference did not match the assembly definition found.

ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

It never checks inside the PrivateBinPath. So to correct my previous question, the DLL never gets loaded despite it being there...

Comment: This is called DLL Hell, not uncommon with plugin scenarios.  You either need to get everything to start using the exact same DLL version or you need to isolate it in its own AppDomain.

Comment: Deleted unrelated answer about strongly signing - this question about probing path where second assembly simply can't be found.

Comment: Yes, I only saw that after running the fusion log viewer...